# How to stop gridview creating a div in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I've got the following asp.net code that generates a listitem dynamically and populates it with a panel that contains a gridview:

```
            Panel panBlocks = new Panel();
            panBlocks.ID = "PanBlockQuestionID" + recordcount.ToString();
            panBlocks.Width = 1300;
            panBlocks.Height = 100;
            panBlocks.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#fabb3d");

            GridView gvEmployee = new GridView();
            gvEmployee.ID = "gvEmployees" + recordcount.ToString();
            gvEmployee.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            gvEmployee.DataSource = dtBlocks;
            gvEmployee.DataBind();
            gvEmployee.Style.Add("position", "relative");
            panBlocks.Controls.Add(gvEmployee);
```

It generates the gridview but wraps it in a div. How do I stop it generating the div as it messes up the styling. The html it generates is:

```
<li id="CPH_Body_liQuestions3" class="liQuestions" style="height:40px;" myCustomIDAtribute="3"><a></a><input type="image" name="ctl00$CPH_Body$lblImg3" id="CPH_Body_lblImg3" class="liQuestionsLabel2" src="../../Images/gtk_cancel.png" style="width:30px;" /><input type="image" name="ctl00$CPH_Body$lblImg3" id="CPH_Body_lblImg3" class="liQuestionsLabel2" src="../../Images/phone_book_edit.png" style="width:30px;" /><span id="CPH_Body_lblID3" class="liQuestionsLabel" style="display:inline-block;width:35px;">298,</span><span id="CPH_Body_lblQuestionType3" class="liQuestionsLabel" style="display:inline-block;width:25px;">1, </span><span id="CPH_Body_lblMsgPrompt3" class="liQuestionsLabel" style="display:inline-block;width:300px;">Fit nylon spacer BG502 to tray,</span><span id="CPH_Body_lblExpectedResp3" class="liQuestionsLabel" style="display:inline-block;width:100px;">YES,</span><span id="CPH_Body_lblImg3" class="liQuestionsLabel" style="display:inline-block;width:30px;"> img: </span><span id="CPH_Body_lblFailMsg3" class="liQuestionsLabel" style="display:inline-block;width:300px;">Not fitted,</span><span id="CPH_Body_lblRetryMsg3" class="liQuestionsLabel" style="display:inline-block;width:300px;">Retry,</span><span id="CPH_Body_lblStart3" class="liQuestionsLabel" style="display:inline-block;width:10px;">,</span><span id="CPH_Body_lblEnd3" class="liQuestionsLabel" style="display:inline-block;width:10px;">,</span><img id="CPH_Body_lblImg3" class="liQuestionsLabel2" onclick="showPanel(&#39;CPH_Body_liQuestions3&#39;)" src="../../Images/block3.png" style="width:30px;" /><div id="CPH_Body_PanBlockQuestionID3" style="background-color:#FABB3D;height:100px;width:1300px;">
    <div>
        <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="gvEmployees3" style="border-collapse:collapse;position:relative;">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">B1ID</th><th scope="col">B1IncEx</th><th scope="col">B1Criteria</th>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>3</td><td>EX</td><td>590P</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div></li>
```

How do I stop the div being generates please as I can't apply styling to it.

Many Thanks

Comment: which div you want to remove? Note that Panel will render as div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [`PlaceHolder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of a `Panel`, the difference is that the `PlaceHolder` is not rendered as a div whereas a `Panel` always.

The `PlaceHolder` control does not produce any visible output and is used only as a container for other controls on the Web page.

Comment: Hi, I've just given it a go but still the same i'm afraid. It seems as if the gridview is creating a div too for itself which I can't apply styling to.

Comment: @codingitup: ah, i remember, that's a known issue and there are multiple questions on SO about it like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166937/how-to-rid-of-empty-div-that-contains-a-gridview). You can't get rid of it easily. Why do you want it? You could surround it with another div to control the style if you want.

Comment: This is not the right answer. Since you can use the same properties that you use with gridviews. 
Can some one else help here thanks. i think you can set a property on the @page on line 1.

Comment: What properties are you talking about? This question is about the div which is rendered when using a panel and also around a GridView. Its not possible to remove the latter, but you can look at the link in my comment to find workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't found a way to remove the DIV *completely*, it is possible to change it so that the DIV no longer wraps the TABLE if you're in a position where you can define and use your own custom `GridView` control.

The trick is to prematurely close the opening DIV tag, so the TABLE follows it in the HTML, rather than being inside it.  If needed, you can also add attributes to the DIV, such as a class name, to ensure that it does not affect the surrounding HTML.

```cs
using System.Web.UI;

public class MyGridView
   : System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView
{
   public MyGridView()
   {
   }

   public override void RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   {
      /* The underlying GridView class renders a DIV as a container in
         RenderControl(), so we can add attributes here, such as a class
         to hide it.
      */
      writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, "hidden");
      base.RenderControl(writer);
   }

   protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   {
      /* We don't want the underlying GridView's container DIV to actually
         wrap the internal TABLE, so calling RenderEndTag() here will cause
         it to be closed before the TABLE is rendered (which happens in
         RenderChildren())...
      */
      writer.RenderEndTag();

      base.RenderContents(writer);

      /* ...However, when this function exits, RenderControl() will call
         RenderEndTag() itself to close what is expected to be the container
         DIV, so we need to provide a open tag for it.  We'll use a SPAN as
         that will have the least effect on the HTML and we could, of
         course, add any required attributes to style it, etc, if required.
      */
      writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Span);
   }

   /* If you need to add any additional attributes to the TABLE tag, you
      can do that here with a call to writer.AddAttribute(); if not, this
      override is redundant.

   protected override void RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   {
      // TODO: call writer.AddAttribute() if required
      base.RenderChildren(writer);
   }
   */
}
```

**HACK ALERT!**
Clearly, this is implementation-specific and subject to change with new versions of ASP.NET.  However, in most cases, an upgrade to the ASP.NET version would most likely require testing/review anyway, so it shouldn't be too much of an issue.